# I need text to move with the resize of a website( I need it to be responsive to the site)

Tags: html, css

I have a page title, I can move it with padding but if I resize the page the text stays in the exact same place. I want it to move with the resize of the page

I've tried taking it out of both of the `divs` it's in. I tried to do `padding: auto`, and using `margins` to move it.

**html:**

```
<div class="bg">
            <div class="title">
                <h1 id="pageTitle">Gypsy Moth Web Works</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**css:**

```
.bg {
      background-image: url("moth.jpg");

        height: 89%;

        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #pageTitle {
        color: hsla(48, 41%, 63%, 1);
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;
        font-size: 80px;
        text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

        margin: 0;
    /*284*/
        padding-top: 284px;
    }
```

Comment: How to move? You want it to stay in the middle of the page?

Comment: Are you saying about responsive ?

Comment: Yea, that's a good way to put it

Comment: If you want the text centered on the page as the window resizes, the CSS you've provided already does that. Can you more clearly explain what you mean by "move with the the resize of the page"?

Comment: Also, it's generally best practice to avoid styling using an ID like `#pageTitle`, because it makes your CSS less reusable. Try adding a class to the `h1` and applying styles on the class instead.

Comment: The text stays in the exact same spot on the page when you resize it, and in-turn it interferes with text below. And thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to center the h1 vertical by adding padd-top:284px which is not a responsive way of centering as the text will always be at that 284px from the top.

A better way to center is to change the properties of the div in which the h1 is a child element. 
In the parent div
add:

display:flex //Turns div into a responsive element

justify-content:center; // Aligns child elements on the center x-axis

align-items:center; // Aligns child elements on the center y-axis

height : (experiment) //choose between relative/responsive or pixel mesuarements to get the desired effect

remove:
top-padding

Example :

```css
.bg {
      background-image: url("moth.jpg");

        height: 100%;

        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #pageTitle {
        color: hsla(48, 41%, 63%, 1);
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;
        font-size: 80px;
        text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        height:50vh;
    /*284*/
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
            <div class="title">
                <h1 id="pageTitle">Gypsy Moth Web Works</h1>
                
                <p>
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the font size. To be simple, imagine text in the middle of the page. when you size your browser to be smaller on the y-axis everything else moves except that one part of text. It then interferes with text below it.

Comment: It could be how you are centering the h1 instead of using padding: 284px set the height of the div to a percenteage then add 

        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;

this will responsivly center if you still want it centered. But where specifically do you want it to be moved? To the left? or closer to the top above the extra content?

Comment: No problems, Ill just change the original answer to better suite